# URL mismatch for Ajax and Htaccess

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a htaccess rewritten but somehow my ajax call never ever reach the respective function in controller. Instead, from buglite console, it displays all the HTML code. I am writing on code igniter and I am totally exhausted regarding this matter. Please help!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>       
        ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
    </IfModule>
```

In the views, attached javascript.

```
$('#logoutbtn').click(function(){

         $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "/fbcontroller/killsession",
            datatype: "json",
            success: function(){
                alert("Logout");
            }
         });
    });
```

Error displayed in buglite.

```
POST /fbcontroller/killsession 404 Not Found 416ms
```

For your information,

I am able to access `http://localhost/fbcontroller/killsession` directly

Comment: Why not just create a JS variable in your header like `var baseUrl = <?php echo base_url(); ?>;` and then use it in your ajax call like `url: baseUrl + "/fbcontroller/killsession",`

Answer (score 0):

This rule appears to be problematic because of wrong regex:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Which is trying to match 0 or more instanced of literal `?`. `?` is not matched in

Replace that rule with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Problem still persist.

Surprisingly, I am able to see the response such as {"Condition":"Error","Message":"Validation failed"}

Comment: Or all HTML of a page since I am redirecting in the killsession() function

Comment: Can you check Apache error.log and see which URL is causing 404?

Comment: <p>The requested URL /user/signin was not found on this server.</p>

Comment: I mean <p>The requested URL /fbcontroller/killsession was not found on this server.</p>

Comment: Ok some questions: Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is location of above .htaccess?

Comment: It is directly under Source File. I have 2 other htaccess under 'Source Files/System' and 'Source Files/application/cache'. Can I remove these 2?

Comment: I can't say that you should remove it but for testing only you can try moving them away.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39348/discussion-between-bryan-wong-and-anubhava)